# Apex-optimized algorithm for "road atlas city distance matrix" style utility data?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, algorithm

I'd like to automate a business process that currently involves a road-atlas-style "distance chart" as seen [here](https://www.destination-nz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/distance-charts_north-island.jpg).

When an employee is hand-reviewing records for deduplication, if a given "status" field contains conflicting values between the two records, they use a chart like the one linked above to determine which value should "win" and be retained in that field on the surviving record (instead of distance, the chart contains a word).

```
    -A- -B- -C-
-B-  B
-C-  A   B
-D-  Z   B   D
```

Like a distance-between-two-cities matrix, it doesn't matter, from a business perspective, which value is "#1" and which is "#2" -- the answer is the same.

There are 50 or so of these "status" fields *(I know ... strange data model ... that's an issue for another day)*, and rather than waste a human's time skimming them by hand while deduplicating, I'd like to write a trigger to intercept the merge and do this particular bit of cleanup automatically.

There are about 20-25 possible input values *(so 190-300 possible outputs)*.  Although there may be **some**, there aren't **many** reliable "rules" for transforming input to output such as "`B` always wins."  *(I tried asking business users to determine such rules, but they couldn't, which is why I provided a road atlas template in Excel and said, "Fine -- fill this in.")*

My question is:  **what is the most efficient data structure for storing the "atlas map," and the most efficient way to access it at compare-time?**

**Particularly if, on occasion, the value at the intersection of two inputs is a *third* word, rather than one of the two inputs themselves?**

Although in theory we could be merging a number of record pairs at a time, in practice we merge one pair at a time, so something that "fires up" efficiently every single execution context is helpful.

**CLARIFICATION**

I am asking a computer science / algorithm question, NOT a "help me understand what my business users want" question.

Let's say that there are no rules -- they monkey-at-a-typewritered the rules.

What is the most efficient way of implementing the "road atlas" as Apex code?

A big 190-300 item switch?

Sorry if not clear about that on my first try.

Comment: I don't think anyone on here can help you understand this problem better. I would sit down with some of the business users & work on getting a better sense of the rules instead.

Comment: @battery.cord -- this seems like a computer science / algorithm question.  I'm not asking for help understanding the business problem.  I understand the problem; I'm just not sure how to efficiently implement the actual lookup of my data in a Java-like programming language.  The "mirror-image #1 & #2" bit I can take care of by passing the input parameters alphabetically, but ... like ... is this just a **300-item switch-when**?  That's more what I'm asking.  I suppose I could've asked on big-StackOverflow but thought folks here would be more familiar with Apex quirks.

Comment: The real issue I have with this question is that I don't understand the problem in the slightest after reading it. Whats your data structure? How do you compare these values? Are they stored in sObjects? How are they related? Where do you store your comparison table? Personally I would lean towards using a custom class with a custom `compareTo` method to compare the different values and then run that in a loop. The `compareTo` would be exactly what you said - just a mess of if statements. With the info provided I really don't see a better way.

Comment: I think some dummy code using a smaller version of your table & simplified data would help other users understand your problem much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

## Step 1: JSON-ize Your Data

Fire up Notepad or some other basic editor, and put in something like the following:

```
{ "a": { "b": "a", "c": "a", "d": "z" },
  "b": { "c": "b", "d": "b" },
  "c": { "d": "d" }
}
```

Note that this is the data from your example, rotated such that the columns are rows and the rows columns.

Carefully note that each value in the row should ideally be a value higher than the key (the first string in each row). This means that for key "b", you should not have an entry for "a". Doing this means less time loading the data structure, and therefore better efficiency. We'll simply swap "A" and "B" values if they're in the wrong order. Also, Let's choose uppercase or lowercase and use just one or the other (maps are case sensitive).

## Step 2: Put The Data In Salesforce

In Setup, create a new [Static Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources.htm&type=5) that contains your JSON file.

## Step 3: Implement The Logic

Your method can be in a utility class, referenced like this:

```
static Map<String, Map<String, String>> statusMap;
static {
  // This block runs if any method in the class is executed.
  StaticResource resource = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'statusmap'];
statusMap = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>)
  JSON.deserialize(resource.Body.toString(), Map<String, Map<String, String>.class);
}
public static String calculateMergeStatus(String value1, String value2) {
  String smaller, larger;
  if(value1 > value2) {
    smaller = value2.toLowerCase();
    larger = value1.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    smaller = value1.toLowerCase();
    larger = value2.toLowerCase();
  }
  return statusMap.containsKey(smaller)? // Make sure there is a value to map
    statusMap.get(smaller).get(larger): // Has value
    null; // No value found
}
```

Note that this code will suffer a bit of performance because of the deserialization process, but has the benefit of being admin-alterable without a new deployment, and should still be sufficiently fast for the 300'ish values.